# jQuery accordion: is there a way to make the scrollbar fit the displayed panel?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a jQuery accordion (jQuery 1.3.2, jQuery UI 1.7.2), with between 3-12 content panels.

Some of the content panels are large, and have lots of content. some are small, and have only a little.

When I expand any of them, the scrollbar on the div containing the accordion (it's got css `overflow: auto;`) is set as if the largest of the panels is expanded.

Let's say I have 3 panels.  One has 3 lines of content, one has 20 lines, and one has 1000 lines.  If I expand either of the first two, the scrollbar indicator gets very very tiny, and moves all the way to the top, even though there is nothing worth scrolling.

Is there a way to fix this?

It seems like [`autoHeight:false`](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion#option-autoHeight) ought to do it, but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: @aSeptik, thanks. that fixed it. if you make it an answer I will accept it and upvote, if you care. I used `autoHeight:false` on the accordion, as well as `height:100%` on the wrapper, and it works. Just like in the link you showed. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to have/set a fixed wrapper height and assign to it the overflow:auto; then put the accordion inside it!

```
<div id="accordion_wrapper">
   <ul id="accordion">
  <li></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

the result should be similar to this:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#no-auto-height

then for style the created overflow scrollbar use

http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html

that is very nice and work for overflow like a charm!